# How to Display All Products in One Page?

Tags: product, product-list, ce-1.8.1.0

I researched and found [this](http://www.noamdesign.com/magento-include-toolbar-and-pagination-when-listing-products/) but it doesnt work for me.

How can I list all products in one page?

Comment: Do you want to display them in a cms page?

Comment: Yes @EvgeniIvanov

Comment: Take a look here http://vishallakhani.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/magento-display-all-products-on-one-page/ and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253389/magento-how-to-display-all-products-in-the-homepage(read the comments)

Comment: I forgot this: Manage Category and make root Category to Is Anchor to “YES” Now, worked! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 8):

I have found another way of implementing this, which has some distinct advantages over the {{block}}-in-a-CMS-page method.

1. Shows the native toolbar, for sorting/pagination
2. Makes your "All" products "page" show up in the category navigation menu (you can change this with "Show In Navigation" dropdown.)
3. Allows you to set the default sorting preferences, to show newest products first, or whatever sorting you desire.

I create a new category, and use the XML Layout Updates to set the template block's category_id to the root category ID of the store.
This makes it so that when I am viewing this "dummy" category, it shows every product in the default category (ie, every product in the store).

Here's the XML (paste this in the category's "Custom Layout Update" under the "Custom Design" tab.)

```
<!-- This is a "dummy" category. When it's shown, we force its' category ID to be 2, causing it to show "All" products -->
<!-- This ONLY works because categoryId:2 is the "Root Category". -->
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setData">
        <key>category_id</key>
        <value>2</value>
    </action>

    <!-- Set the available sort methods, defaulting to Newest. -->
    <action method="setAvailableOrders" json="value">
        <value><![CDATA[{"created_at" : "Newest","price":"Price"}]]></value>
    </action>
</reference>

<!-- Default to DESCENDING order, to show newest products first -->
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setDefaultDirection">
        <dir>desc</dir>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: It's given "THERE ARE NO PRODUCTS MATCHING THE SELECTION." But already there are products

Comment: then try to add the category id in the code like `category_id="your Category id"` and see what is happening there

Comment: When I write sub category id it's working but root category id given the same message. Why is diffent? How can I list all category's products?.

Comment: Go to Manage Category and make root Category to Is Anchor to “YES”. It's worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest my free open-source extension which does it - <strike>https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/CustomListing</strike>

> Unfortunately Tim has deleted his repo, try this fork: https://github.com/ho-nl/CustomListing

Comment: Your link is dead, it shows an 404 Error :(

Comment: updated the link

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to display all products on my Magento home page using the following reference: https://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-add-and-display-all-products-on-homepage-in-magento

[image]
**To display all products on Magento homepage**

In Magento backend, go to CMS -> Manage pages > Homepage and add this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

**To Display products from a specific category to homepage**

Go to CMS -> Pages > Homepage and add the follow code to HTML editor of Homepage

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Replace category_id="3" with your desired category ID

Hope this helps